# Is this Sequence Diagram correctly drawn from this code?

Tags: reverse-engineering, diagram, sequence-diagram, visual-paradigm

I have to draw a Sequence Diagram using only this piece of code (as part of an University assignment). Here is my idea of what the diagram would look like, but I would really like if somebody with more experience could check it and give me any feedback. 
My biggest dilemma is the following lines: 
- private Alarm alarm = GlobalSettings.GetCurrentAlarmSetting();//do I make a create message here (as I did), or? 
- lights = lightsController.GetAllLights();//did I do this correctly? I have no idea how to represent an equation operator.

Unfortunately, I had to crop it into 2 pictures:

[image]
[image]

```
public class AlarmController
    {
        private Alarm alarm = GlobalSettings.GetCurrentAlarmSetting();
        private User user = GlobalSettings.GetHouseOwner();
        private LightsController lightsController = new LightsController();

        public void ActivateSecurityMeasures(Sensor sensor)
        {
            List<Light> lights; 
            if (alarm.IsActivated())
            {
                lights = lightsController.GetAllLights();
                alarm.ActivateSoundAlarm();
                user.SendNotification("Home alarm is activated");
            }
            else
                lights = lightsController.GetSensorLights(sensor); 

            foreach (Light item in lights)
            {   item.TurnOn(); }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Alarm and User should not be create using Creation message since your source code didn't show the two objects are created from AlarmController. They just retrieve from static operation in GlobalSettings. And seems the message #8.3, #8.8, #8.9 & #8.10 are also unnecessar since #8.2 & #8.7 return the light imply AlarmController having reference to Light object and available to call in #8.11